# Custom loss function in keras (calculate loss based on chosen neurons)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer, autoencoder

I'm building autoencoder for system recommendation and I want to calculate loss based for example on 200 outputs instead of 500 neurons (data with 500 columns as below).
In other words when calculating loss we can assign input[:,200:500] = 0 and output[:,200:500] = 0, so this neuruons doesnt matter when learning.
Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import numpy
from keras import layers
from keras import backend as K
from keras import Model
import pandas as pd


data = np.random.rand(1000, 500) # not my data, just example
latent_dim = 8

# encoder
encoder_input = keras.Input(shape=(data.shape[1]), name="encoder_input")
x = layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(encoder_input)
encoder_output = layers.Lambda(units=latent_dim, name="encoder_output")(z)
encoder = Model(encoder_input, encoder_output, name='encoder_model')

# decoder
decoder_input = keras.Input(shape=latent_dim)
x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoder_input)
decoder_output = layers.Dense(data.shape[1], activation='relu')(x)
decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoder_output, name='decoder_model')

# autoencoder
ae_input = keras.Input(shape=(data.shape[1]))
ae_encoder_output = encoder(ae_input)
ae_decoder_output = decoder(ae_decoder_output)
ae = keras.Model(ae_input, ae_decoder_output, name='ae')

def vae_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    reconstruction_loss = K.square(y_true - y_pred)
    
    return reconstruction_loss

ae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=vae_loss)
ae.fit(data, data, epochs=10)
```

I tried to modify custom loss function. I googled some solutions and  was trying to change tensors **y_true** and **y_pred** but erros occurs. Also i cant change this tensors to numpy arrays. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems much easier to simply use `y_true[:, :200]` and do the same for the predictions and compute the difference of those.

Comment: @xdurch0 You are right. But I wanted to ask something else (my mistake). Maybe you know how I can choose inputs different from 0 and outputs with same index as input?